# I'm not getting the Welcome screen showing before my Android Studio opens

Tags: android

I just installed my Android Studio but at first I had a couple of problems getting it started due to having linked it to the wrong path, though I eventually managed to get the correct path linking to my SDk. I don't necessarily have any problem starting my Android IDE, however it doesn't start as usual with the weclome screen where I can just easily access "new Project" and co. Is this just fine and should I not look after fixing that and just start my project from the main software or should I look to get my Welcome page showing, and if so how could I do that?

Comment: When you open Android Studio, you will be redirected to your last opened project. Is that the case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is totally fine. Android Studio will always load the last project you were working on. If Android Studio is loading you can cancel the project to get to the "Welcome Screen". Also if the project has completely loaded you can use:

File -> Close Project

to get to the "Welcome Screen". 
If you want to start the Welcome Screen without loading the last project go to:

File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Un-check "Reopen last project on startup" -> Click apply

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful

Comment: I`m glad to help you, please mark my answer as the solution for your question :)

Comment: This is the first time I've seen the "Close Project" option. I don't know how I missed it before.